# selecting a specified character only in a string using jquery select() method

Tags: jquery

For example 
   if there is a textbox contains value as  "123@sample".

Using this code

```
$('#PIN_ITM_Code').focus().select();
```

it select all 123@sample.

Now what i want is only the 123. I have tried this code but have error like focus is not a function.

```
var $this = $('#PIN_ITM_Code').val().split('@')[0];
$this.focus().select();
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: the focus is for the input field, not for a string or something

Comment: Do you want this http://jsfiddle.net/apumtae6/ ?

Comment: @devqon is there anyway to select the string with only the character that i want?

Comment: @laaposto no i want the 123 selected during focus

Comment: what do you mean by focus, what do you expect the 123 to do?

Comment: @devqon i want the 123 will only be selected when focus. So that if i change it only the 123 will be change like for example 124

Comment: Now I see, you don't want the user be able to alter the `@sample`. I suggest to put the `@sample` after the input box rather than in it: `<input type="text" /><span>@sample</span>`

Comment: it should be part of the textbox that needs to be input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focus is of jquery to focus a form element. But in your code $this holds string returned by split. so it will throw an error.

There is javascript method "setSelectionRange" which can select specific part of text in input box.

so your code will be

```
var value= $('#PIN_ITM_Code').val();
var index=value.indexOf("@");

$('#PIN_ITM_Code')[0].setSelectionRange(0,index-1)
```

Comment: yayy thanks you so much.. got what i want after removing -1 $('#PIN_ITM_Code')[0].setSelectionRange(0, index)

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
var numericonly = $('#PIN_ITM_Code').val().split('@')[0];
alert(numericonly);
```

Comment: i want it selected after an event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it via jQuery. Try this.

```
<input type="text" value="123@sample" />
<button id="a">test</button>
<script>
$.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            this.focus();
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if (this.createTextRange) {
            var range = this.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', start);
            range.select();
        }
    });
};
$("#a").click(function (){
    var i = $("input").val().indexOf("@");
    $('input').selectRange(i,i + 1);
});
</script>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WpqsN/2031/)